# JAXB get raw content of element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a XML structure like this:

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c>
        content
      </c>
   </b>
</a>
```

I have a class B, duly annotated, which has an attribute C and both are being parsed correctly. However, for specific reasons (c might have different elements, not known in advanced) I need to get the raw content of the c element.

Does anybody have any idea how to do it?

- By the way, I don't have any control on the XML file, so it is not an option to change its structure
- I have tried to get it as a String. It did not worked.

Thank you in advanced for your help!